# How do I convert lines of sentences into a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a `.tsv` file where there are lines of sentences. I want to put each line into a tuple and I want the end result to be a list of tuples. My end result is a list of one tuple with all lines combined instead of a list of tuples with each line in a tuple

Example `.tsv` file sample:

```
1 This is a sentence
2 This is also a sentence
3 This is also a sentence
```

My Code:

```
result = []
with open(path + "sentences.tsv", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    result.append(tuple(lines))
print(result)
```

My Output:

```
[('1 This is a sentence\n', '2 This is also a sentence\n', '3 This is also a sentence')]
```

Expected Output:

```
[('1', 'This is a sentence'), ('2', 'This is also a sentence'), ('3', 'This is also a sentence')]
```

Comment: can you upload the `tsv` file?

Comment: Get rid of `.readlines()`. You need to iterate the file. `result = [tuple(line) for line in f]` might do it. Or, if you're numbering it yourself: `result = [(i+1, line) for i, line in enumerate(f)]`

Comment: `[(s[:s.index(' ')],s[(1+s.index(' ')):]) for s in f]` ? It would help if you explained the structure of the lines in more detail.

Comment: Use the supplied duplicate *without* `split`ting the lines.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. Iterating solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
result = []
with open(path + "sentences.tsv", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        result.append(tuple(line.replace('\n','').split('\t')))
print(result)
```

Comment: Instead of ```line.replace('\n', '')```, it is better to use ```line.strip()```.

Comment: Instead of any string manipulation at all, use `csv.reader` with `delimiter='\t'`, because TSV is not just "split on tabs".